# In MS Excel, concatenation of two cell such that it could appear in two line in same cell

Tags: excel

In MS Excel, Lets cell A5 and B5 has some text. I want to concatenate these text such that it could appear in two line in same cell. Could you please provide the solution?

Comment: Yes its possible in which cell you want to concatenate data? A5 or B5 or different?

Comment: Are you looking for VBA code or just a way to do this directly from Excel?

Comment: `=A5 & CHAR(10) & B5`  You will need to enable text wrapping in the cell with the formula

Answer (score 2):

If only option is excel formula then use as following or you have to use vba code.

```
=A5 & CHAR(10) & B5
```

Enable `Wrap text` for the cell where you put formula. See below screenshot.

[image]